# pandas - calculate mean across date columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set with multiple columns whose names are dates.  An example is here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'company': ['dell', 'microsoft', 'toshiba', 'apple'], 
               'measure': ['sales', 'speed', 'wait time', 'service'], 
               'category': ['laptop', 'tablet', 'smartphone', 'desktop'], 
               '10/6/2015': [234, 333, 456, 290], 
               '10/13/2015': [134, 154, 123, 177], 
               '10/20/2015': [57, 57, 63, 71]})
```

I would like to calculate the mean for each month.  So for the example above, I would like the desired result to be:

```
     company    measure    category  201510
0       dell      sales      laptop  141.66
1  microsoft      speed      tablet  181.33
2    toshiba  wait time  smartphone  214.00
3      apple    service     desktop  179.33
```

Where `201510` is the mean of the three date columns in `df`.  Is there a way to do this with multiple date columns using, say, `groupby`?  Any help would be appreciated, I am a complete newby when it comes to python.  Should I use a time-series approach or is there a straightforward way to do this via `pandas`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `filter` `like` filter the columns, then we convert the columns to `datetime` and using `groupby`

```
s=df.filter(like='/')
s.columns=pd.to_datetime(s.columns).strftime('%Y-%m')
pd.concat([df,s.groupby(level=0,axis=1).mean()],axis=1)
Out[229]: 
     company    measure     ...     10/20/2015     2015-10
0       dell      sales     ...             57  141.666667
1  microsoft      speed     ...             57  181.333333
2    toshiba  wait time     ...             63  214.000000
3      apple    service     ...             71  179.333333
[4 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: this is great!  What if I just want the columns with the `mean` value?

Comment: @jvalenti `pd.concat([df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains('/')],s.groupby(level=0,axis=1).mean()],axis=1)
`